# Android - Update ProgressBar from service, is it possible?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm trying to update a progressbar from a service. I don't know if this is the correct way or not, but I have to do that. In the service, I'm trying to upload images and it will return a progress for the notification bar. Now, I want to add a progress bar as the indicator and remove the notification at the notif bar.

These are the codes that I use for calling the ProgressBar

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doc, null);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.imgProgressBar);
```

It doesn't return any error, but when I tried to update the progressBar with

> progressBar.setProgress(progress)

Nothing's happened.. What should I do to, is there anything wrong with my code?

Will appreciate any input. Thanks

Comment: More better way would be use async task which let you update progressbar, In service there are binded services which lets you communicate to ui

Comment: hi, but I tried to do the setProgress on onCreate(), it's still not working. So my first objective is to update the progressBar first then will try with Async

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057565/update-progressbar-from-a-service-started-by-a-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Dont worry, sometimes it just takes minor extra effort to get things work, check this link and read it thouroughly - http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-progressbars

Comment: @geniushkg , thanks for the input, ill try to check it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it is not correct way to update you Progress bar ...
you should use Broadcast receiver to update your Activity or Fragment as per Service

From Service you should sendBroadCast

```
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);       
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

For Activity or Framgent

```
private MyBroadRequestReceiver receiver;
```

on onCreate

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME);
 receiver = new MyBroadRequestReceiver();
registerReceiver( receiver, filter);
```

and

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

And in your Activity or Fragment in Which you Want to update Progress bar

```
public class MyBroadRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         //update your progressbar here

        }


    }
```

Comment: hi, ya, but I was trying to update the progressbar from a Service, not from Activity and Fragment :(

Comment: Service don't have any view so you should update your Progress bar where it is on Activity or Fragment.if you find it Useful you can mark it as True,thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Service Has No UI
so if You want to communicate between Service and UI (Activity)

you should user BroadCast

In Your Service you can Add this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Actionname");
            intent.putExtra("....",.......);
            intent.putExtra(".",...);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and in Your Activity

```
private class BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("reciverlocation"))
            {  // what you wane to do

}}
```

and dont forget to add Receiver in your manifest

Answer (score 1):

If your activity is running, you may use an `interface` for the same -

**Step 1: Define interface in your `service` -**

```
public interface OnProgressUpdateListener {

    void onProgressUpdate(int progress);
}
```

**Step 2: Create setter for listener -**

```
private static OnProgressUpdateListener progressListener;
public static void setOnProgressChangedListener(OnProgressUpdateListener _listener) {
        progressListener = _listener;
}
```

**Step 3: implement `listener` into your `activity**

```
MyService.setOnProgressChangedListener(this);
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
    // Do update your progress...
}
```

**PS, Don't forget to set it to `null`.. since it is `static`**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MyService.setOnProgressChangedListener(null);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i will get back to you for the result